# Special CHaracter

Tags: xml, parsing, special-characters

I have a XML in String format with special characters as "<>&" and want to parse the XML. What is the best way to escape the special characters. I know the source should be corrected . but thats not possible.(Consider a bug in THird party product which is outdated).
Req.Also the rest tags in XML should not change

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmc-service-illust SYSTEM "../../dtd/tmc-illust.dtd">
<data-service-illust>
    <indicateinfo>
        <line points="0,0 0,0" strokedash="0" whiteedge="false" />
        <ptxt>**<B>** & <5></ptxt>
    </indicateinfo>
</data-service-illust>
```

Comment: When you say you "have an XML", what you mean is that you have some data which you want to convert to XML. Since it's not (well-formed) XML, you can't use a parser to process it. Many errors (eg "<" not followed by "[", "!", or a letter) can be picked up fairly easily with regular expressions, but the general problem of repairing bad XML is difficult and not well-defined, which is why the specification requires these characters to be escaped in the first place.

Comment: For what it's worth, the last time I had this problem the first thing I did was to raise a bug report with the company that had the audacity to charge me for software that was clearly unfit for purpose, and the next thing I did was to spend half an hour editing the bad data by hand until it parsed.